# Where GPU read/write data

Tags: matlab, parallel-processing, gpu, cpu-architecture

I am trying to understand below lines from [here](https://www.mathworks.com/help/parallel-computing/measuring-gpu-performance.html)

**How quickly can data be sent to the GPU or read back from it?**

**How fast can the GPU kernel read and write data?**

How quickly can data be sent to the GPU? Which peripheral device sent data to GPU? Where GPU kernel read and write data? to the data bus?

Is [this](https://www.mathworks.com/help/parallel-computing/measuring-gpu-performance.html) implementation showing us how everything [GPU and other peripheral devices] contribute towards computation performance?

Comment: I don't quite understand the question. The page does give a measurement, doesn't it? Of course that result is for a specific hardware, and other hardware will have significantly different measurements.

Comment: CPU memory is in RAM, but GPUs have their own RAM. Transfer times tend to be 2Gb/s, or 12GB/s if memory is page-locked (which matlab may do). Then, once there, the kernel reads data slower than it can compute a sum (around x200 slower), but the times depends on your hardware. This last bit is irrelevant for MATLAB usage.

Comment: Thank you Ander, Can I show this implementation as a GPU Performance measure and contribution of other peripheral in computation or this whole implementation is specific to matlab?

Comment: "Can I show this implementation..." Honestly, I would not, unless you understand it. An implementation is always specific to a language. The algorithm may not be.

Comment: As I am very new to Computer Architecture, I am trying to understand that if this implementation is showing the computation performance or its showing the algorithm performance?

Comment: If I have to show practically the performance of GPU vs CPU and other peripherals of my system, then I can use this implementation?